# sql not in and in oporators

Tags: sql, oracle

HI I am unable to filter materials that belong to only specific list.

```
Select material 
from price 
where region='04' 
  and pricelist ='5' 
  and pricelist not in ('4','6','7');
```

I want only those materials which are unique only in pricelist 5 and not in any other pricelists. how can i get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this (alternately, you could do a self-join, but I think this is just as easy, if not easier, to understand):

```
SELECT material
  FROM price a
 WHERE region = '04'
   AND pricelist = '5'
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM price b
                     WHERE b.material = a.material
                       AND b.region = a.region
                       AND b.pricelist != a.pricelist )
```

What the above will do will find values of `material` in `region` '04' where the `pricelist` is '5' while excluding those same materials *in the same region* but on a different price list.

Comment: Great answer david. Could you please tell me what was the mistake i wan doing? and please explain what select 1 will do in your querry? .. your answer is workin for me :) Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT 1` is just a dummy value since all you're doing is checking for existence. It could be `'X'` or `'Y'` or `'Z'` - won't matter. Basically `NOT EXISTS` above is just checking to see if there is a matching material in the same region but on a different price list. Let me know if you need more info - and please accept the answer if it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your current query will only return results `where pricelist = 5` -- the `not in` statement is irrelevant unless it exclude that record.  It sounds like you want to return any material which matches on the 5, but doesn't have any other non-5 matches.

One option is to use `exist`.  Here's another option using conditional aggregation with `max` and `case` which eliminates the need for multiple queries:

```
select material 
from (
  select material,
    max(case when pricelist = '5' then 1 else 0 end) haspl5, 
    max(case when pricelist != '5' then 1 else 0 end) hasothers
  from price 
  where region='04' 
  group by material
) t
where haspl5 = 1 and hasothers != 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8276a/2)